# "An Even Blacker Death", This Time in the 21st Century

Tags: society, culture, post-apocalypse, diseases

Long ago, I asked a question as to how the culture of Europe would be affected if, [instead of one-quarter or half of medieval Europe's population got killed by the black death but two out of three or three out of four](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33499/an-even-blacker-death).  But now let's reimagine this scenario to the present day.

Europe, as of 2016, has a population of 741.4 million people.  But now a new virulent strain of the old bubonic plague has killed off two-thirds or three-quarters of the continent's population in only three short years.  The denser the population of a city, the closer the death rate would be to absolute.  In perspective, Paris, the densest city in Europe, would suffer a hit rate of 100%.

The question is the same as before--how would the increased severity of the Black Death affect European culture and society?

Comment: Bubonic plague simply wouldn’t kill that many people. It responds well to antibiotics. You need a virus, not a bacterium.

Comment: Nope. Not with a 10 foot stick.

Comment: @MikeScott We aren't sure the Black Death was 100% bubonic plague, it doesn't fit the description. See this blog, it details some of the controversy: https://www.nature.com/scitable/blog/viruses101/could_the_black_death_actually

Comment: Modern epidemiology makes controlling the spread of disease much easier.  Also, this feels crazy broad.

Comment: @Amadeus The question specifies bubonic plague.

Comment: You will need something less treatable than a bacterial infection, that can be treated with a standard course of antibiotics. A mutation of the Ebola virus (see the link at my previous comment) would do it. But then, my question is, why is this limited to Europe? In the modern world, an Ebola-type virus (hemorrhagic fever inducing) with a long incubation period (several weeks during which a person is infected without symptoms) should devastate the entire world.

Comment: You can have a virus *or* you can go with mycobacteria.  Mycobacteria causes leprosy, tuberculosis and a few others.  These little guys are exceptionally hard to kill.

Comment: @MikeScott The OP first references the **black death**, and I assume doesn't know there is any controversy over the nature of it. Whatever caused the Black Death fits closer to an ebola-type virus than the bubonic plague. And it might have been both.

Comment: Antibiotic resistant "superbugs" are a reality of early 21st century medicine. It is not a stretch of the imagination to see an antibiotic resistant strain of  Yersinia pestis developing and escaping to the wild. See https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Suzanne_Chanteau/publication/13943049_Multidrug_Resistance_in_Yersinia_pestis_Mediated_by_a_Transferable_Plasmid/links/562faacd08aeaeb679a25323.pdf

Comment: Most questions about "how would \[something\] affect culture and society?" are closed, and rightly so. See [Is broad impact of a specific change too broad?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6059/809)

Comment: There are all kinds of "what would happen if most of the population was killed off" questions already. I don't see how this is substantially different.

Comment: @Mołot  Then why did you leave this open?  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33499/an-even-blacker-death?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @John plural or singular "you"? I don't remember if two years ago I was even able to review, and if I have seen that one.

Comment: I have to agree with Mołot, and I’ve voted to close both questions since asking about effects on “European culture and society” is simply enormously broad.

Comment: @Dubukay  "Broad" is a vaguely written sentence or singular paragraph that provides no specifics.  How is this "broad"?

Comment: @Amadeus That was an interesting read with a lot of conjectures. As for the reliability of that blog... the 3 references are all linked back to 2 Dr's who wrote a book. Not a research paper, a book. Its an interesting read but thats about it.

Comment: @Shadowzee I said there is debate. I am a full time scientist and more interested in the validity of the arguments than I am in who made  them; I put no credence in either ad hominem attack or **support**, nor do I subscribe to proof (or negation) by popularity. Everybody believing the world is flat doesn't make it flat, and 99.9% of geologists denied plate tectonics for decades, the theory was still right. The article details real puzzles concerning the Black Death impossible to explain by yersinia pestis alone. Judge it on its merits! Scientific truth is not determined by popularity contest.

Comment: @JohnWDailey the test we normally use on StackOverflow is the “book test”. Could I write an entire book about this without running out of things to say? Yes. I could discuss the politics of various regions, the economic impacts from both a theoretical and applied standpoint, the migration and movement patterns of people both into and out of the area, the sociological isolation that arises when you can no longer talk to people for fear of catching a virus, etc. Since I could write a “book” about any of those and still be answering your question, it is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect in the modern world, losing 75% of the population means things collapse. Unlike the Middle Ages, there are basically no settlements that are self-sufficient in terms of food, energy, manufacturing, jobs, delivery or basic services like health care.

In the MA, towns were surrounded by farms that provided the town with food, they used no electricity for refrigeration, sanitation, water delivery and disposal. Their transportation and muscle, instead of being machines, was muscular (human, horse, donkey, ox). Those animals don't really exist in usable numbers any more. The resources don't exist.

Your best bet would be mass migration of the remaining 25% to one of the big cities, before they frikkin' starve, where they can again join together and make a modern population. But you have the problem of **feeding and watering** them, with 75% of the people that normally managed that effort and maintained and operated the machinery (like trucks or power plants) dead. You can't operate a power plant with 25% of its former staff (or we would do that already), and you can't just assign a former store clerk and say "You're an electrician now, get in there." The same with all the other jobs: Unlike the middle ages, education and training are a necessity of most jobs.

Everything breaks down; schools, colleges, banks, stores, farms and other productions.

Your best bet for survival is forced relocation of survivors to get enough trained people back together to run cities and farms. Basically this will be, at least temporarily, a form of forced socialism. it doesn't have to be *communism*, but it would have to be a cooperative effort to get back on their feet, a taking of the abandoned farms to harvest, an assignment of workers to necessary projects. All old companies are devastated by the same 75% loss of workers, they must all be dissolved and a new system created from the parts. Thus a redistribution of property to make sure we work in the most efficient way possible to save our own damn lives.

The good news is, all the machinery and likely all the crops and most of the food animals are still viable resources. If we put enough experts together in harvesting and transporting, that will at least feed the newly centralized population (there may be more than one centralization point, perhaps one or more per country, depending on how many millions survived).

With that devastating a blow, I am not sure we can project with any certainty what the changed culture will look like. Eventually (within a generation or so) it should revert to the current day. The survivors will be considerably richer than they were, with about 4x more resources. But I do think some control centers will arise quickly, probably from the original governments deploying whatever survived from their armies.

It's all guesses, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84838/discussion-between-aaron-and-amadeus).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84866/discussion-on-answer-by-amadeus-an-even-blacker-death-this-time-in-the-21st-c).

Answer (score 1):

This scenario reminds me of [The Long Loud Silence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Loud_Silence).

It is difficult for me to talk about *culture and society* given the death toll. If that many people die, then society will most likely collapse and the survivors will rather form *small groups* (i.e. a term often referred in psychology) or seek refuge alone (as in the book by Wilson Tucker referred above).

I'd really like to link resources on *small group psychology* but I also don't want to push personal preferences on the subject. I think however that it is an important subject because it covers many different aspects — verbal communication for instance which will be rather difficult given the abundance of spoken languages in Europe; also any other form of interaction (e.g. games, trades, fights, etc.) where different cultures adore different games, similarly value different goods more and fight over different things. So what I'm trying to get to here in a nut shell is that society will be partitioned around similar cultures due to easier interactions.

And now back to where I started — with The Long Loud Silence — it is focused on the individual who is desperate for social interaction, but simply can't get any of it because of the circumstances (i.e. starvation and constant threat). Things change however on the long run, but it takes significant amount of time. So I guess in such a scenario one may expect rather predatorial culture at first and a slowly emerging society through the merger of groups or the formation of unions.